# Как сделать фото адаптивным на всех экранах?

Tags: html, css, adaptive

Суть вопроса такой --> У меня есть ссылка  без ничего, у него задний фон изображения.
Я бы хотел задать ему максимальный размер 137px | и 71px -. Если написать max блок пропадает, не знаю как быть.

```css
.navbar {}

.navbar-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 1180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 25px;
}

.navbar-list-item {}

.navbar-list-item:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.navbar-logo {
  display: block;
  width: 137px;
  height: 72px;
  background: url(/src/assets/img/icons/logo.svg), black;
}

.navbar-list-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-btn {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<nav className="navbar">
  <ul className="navbar-list">
    <li className="navbar-list-item">
      <a className="navbar-logo" href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li className="navbar-list-item">
      <a className="navbar-list-link" href="#">Главная</a>
    </li>
    <li className="navbar-list-item">
      <a className="navbar-list-link" href="#">Про гида</a>
    </li>
    <li className="navbar-list-item">
      <a className="navbar-list-link" href="#">Программа тура</a>
    </li>
    <li className="navbar-list-item">
      <a className="navbar-list-link" href="#">Стоимость</a>
    </li>
    <li className="navbar-list-item">
      <a className="navbar-list-link" href="#">Блог</a>
    </li>
    <li className="navbar-list-item">
      <a className="navbar-list-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button className="navbar-btn">Консультация</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```